# How to calculate vanity address using C?

Tags: addresses

I have a curiosity about tacking on zeroes to strings, and Ethereum addresses are no exception. I wrote my own python program, and it was too slow. I wrote the program at https://pastebin.com/hTFGiKzR and I'm just curious about if there is a C program like "profanity" that is faster that runs on CPU.